# Double Fourier series - value at a point

Tags: series-expansion, fourier-analysis

I would like to receive the value of the series at point x->1,y->1. Where is the mistake?

````
De[E_,h_,v_]:=((E*h^3)/(12*(1-v^2)))
Alf[a_]:=((m*Pi)/a)
Bet[b_]:=((n*Pi)/b)
q[P_,a_,b_,x0_,y0_]:=((4P)/(a*b))*Sin[Alf[a]*x0]*Sin[Bet[b]*y0]
Delt[E_,h_,v_,a_,b_]:=De[E,h,v](Alf[a]^2+Bet[b]^2)^2
w[P_,a_,b_,x0_,y0_,E_,h_,v_]:=q[P,a,b,x0,y0]/Delt[E,h,v,a,b]
Mx[E_,h_,v_,a_,b_,P_,x0_,y0_,x_,y_]:=De[E,h,v]*Sum[Sum[((Alf[a]^2+v*Bet[b]^2)*w[P,a,b,x0,y0,E,h,v])*Sin[Alf[a]*x]*Sin[Bet[b]*y],{n,1,20}],{m,1,20}],{x,0,6},{y,0,4}
Mx[E,h,v,a,b,P,x0,y0,x,y]/.{E->27000000000,h->0.2,v->0.2,a->6,b->4,P->10000,x0->5,y0->3,x->1,y->1}```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cleaned up your code so it looks like this:

```
De[e_, h_, v_] := ((e h^3)/(12 (1 - v^2)))
Alf[a_] := ((m Pi)/a)
Bet[b_] := ((n Pi)/b)
q[p_, a_, b_, x0_, y0_] := ((4 p)/(a b)) Sin[Alf[a] x0] Sin[Bet[b] y0]
Delt[e_, h_, v_, a_, b_] := De[e, h, v] (Alf[a]^2 + Bet[b]^2)^2
w[p_, a_, b_, x0_, y0_, e_, h_, v_] := q[p, a, b, x0, y0]/Delt[e, h, v, a, b]
Mx[e_, h_, v_, a_, b_, p_, x0_, y0_, x_, y_] :=
  De[e, h, v] *
    Sum[
      Sum[
        ((Alf[a]^2 + 
          v Bet[b]^2) w[p, a, b, x0, y0, e, h, v]) Sin[Alf[a] x] Sin[Bet[b] y], 
        {n, 1, 20}], 
      {m, 1, 20}]
```

With this version, evaluating

```
Mx[27000000000, 0.2, 0.2, 6, 4, 10000, 5, 3, 1, 1]
```

gives

> `-9.34095`

Does that look like a correct result to you?

Note

Putting `,{x, 0, 6}, {y, 0, 4}` at the end of your definition of `Mx` seems to be where your problem arises.

Comment: I would like the function to be limited by {x, 0, 6}, {y, 0, 4} and then know the value at x-> 1, y->

Comment: @Peter. `Mx[e_, h_, v_, a_, b_, p_, x0_, y0_, x_/;0<=x<=6, y_/;0<=y<=4] := ...` is one way to do it. But whether it should done this way or some other way or at all is a completely different question than the one you asked here. You would need to describe how you will use `Mx` in further computations to get a meaningful answer,

Comment: Dear @m_goldberg, this is exactly what I wanted to receive. Thank you for taking the time to solve my problem.

Comment: @Peter. I'm glad you find my answer useful. Please consider accepting it. You can do that by clicking on the check mark that appears on the left of the answer below the down arrow.